# Does xdmp:database-backup-validate also checks for disk size?

Tags: marklogic

I have a scenario where I want to check whether enough disk space is available or not before scheduling full backup in MarkLogic. I am aware that there is a validation phase.Here all backup directories are checked, that they exist and are writable, whether there is disk space available or not ? Is this the API that can externally do the same thing ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is part of what does from my understanding. It is used in the core of the backup code as part of the backup process defined [HERE](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/backup_restore).

If you are wondering what some of the things are that are checked by the function, here is a snippet of status strings returned in one of the elements (I found by analysing the admin code used to register a forest backup). You can see the various errors that may be returned from the tests specifically related to the target backup directory:

```
"non-existent"
"in-use"
"corrupt"
"no-access"
"no-space"
"is-install-dir"
"is-data-dir"
"is-public-data-dir"
"bad-path-separator"
```